# A copy/paste file cannot be added to git stage

Tags: java, git, egit

I have an `eclipse` project which is under version control using `eGit`.

I copied a java file and pasted with a new name in a new package. I changed the content of the file, but I can see the new file in unstaged changes.

Can you please help me to add it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you go on the console to your project root directory and do 'git status', do you see your file listed?

Comment: @andrralv No I can't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that my file was included in `.gitignore` file.

I used the `eclipse` terminal and move to the directory that contains the file.

Then I used

```
git add -f filename.java
```

Now I can see the file in unstage changes file list.